# Bash Script to Conda Install requirements.txt with PIP follow-up

Tags: python, bash, pip, anaconda

When installing a requirements.txt file for a Django app on a linux server I can run:

```
conda install --yes --file requirements.txt
```

This will crash if any of the packages are not available through Conda (`PackageNotFoundError`).  This bash one liner is a cool way to go through the requirements.txt file one line at a time [source](https://gist.github.com/luiscape/19d2d73a8c7b59411a2fb73a697f5ed4):

```
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement; done < requirements.txt
```

This installs all of the packages that are available through Conda without crashing on the first missing package.  However, what I would like to is track the packages that fail by capturing the output from Conda and if there is a `PackageNotFoundError` then run pip install on the package.

I'm not great with bash, so hoping someone can suggest a hack.  Another solution could be to just write out a new text file called `pip-requirements.txt` with the requirements that fail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a solution:

Run this to install with conda or pip if the package is not available to conda:

```
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement || pip install $requirement; done < requirements.txt
```

Once it's done you can use conda to export the environment yaml:

```
conda env export > environment.yml
```

Comment: It should be noted that mixing conda and pip like this can lead to dependencies being installed twice. (because pip cannot see conda dependencies I think?)

Answer (score 8):

Personally I find the Anaconda environment & package management to be outstanding. So if you're using the `conda` command to update your packages in your python environment then I recommend using the `environment.yml` file instead of `requirements.txt`.

The `environment.yml` should looks like the following:

```
name: root            # default is root
channels:
- defaults
dependencies:         # everything under this, installed by conda
- numpy==1.13.3
- scipy==1.0.0
- pip:                # everything under this, installed by pip
  - Flask==0.12.2
  - gunicorn==19.7.1
```

The command to install:

```
conda env update --file environment.yml
```

#### Note:

Here we set `name: root` which is the default anaconda environment name. This is not standard practice of how to use the `conda` and `environment.yml` file. Ideally every python project should have its own `environment.yml` file with a project specific environment name i.e. `name: project-name`.  Please go through https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html on using Anaconda for package management.

Comment: This is cool, thanks, it would mean I would have to look through a pretty long list of dependencies and parse them out.  Also, other members of my team are working on the same repo and not using Anaconda, so I would have to test and update for each new dependency that they add to requirements.txt.  Now you've got me thinking it would be even cooler to have a script to read through requirements.txt and produce the environment.yml file.

Comment: You're welcome! Also I don't know what you're working on so I might be wrong in your case but I found out early on that the dependency list for any project is usually pretty small, around 20. However the number of packages installed in your environment might be huge mostly because your dependencies end up installing many of their own dependencies. For example installing `Flask` will also install along with it `Werkzeug`, `click`, `Jinja2` etc. But you only need to have `Flask` in your `requirements.txt` or `environment.yml`.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on a pretty mature Django project so there are 50 some odd packages in the `requirements.txt` file, I bet a few of them are redundant.  I found out that you can export the `environment.yml` with `conda env export > environment.yml`, which is pretty slick.  See my answer below.

Comment: My personal opinion is that using `conda env export` is not a great idea precisely for the reasons I mentioned above. It might be very useful in the case where you're developing a one time application which isn't intended to be maintained. But if you have a project that needs to be maintained over a long period of time, doing a complete dump of the environment into the `environment.yml` file will lead to many versioning conflicts in the very near future because `environment.yml` files use precise `==` versioning where as package sub-dependencies often use more open ended `>=` versioning.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is the best dep mgmt answer I've seen. To clarify other's concern, it should be noted that the yml file CAN have version number omitted or defined by a range, transitive dependencies can also be omitted. SO it probably make sense to write the yml file instead of generating it

Answer (score 1):

Redirect stderr to a file:

```
while read requirement; do conda install --yes $requirement; done < requirements.txt 2>error.log
```

Comment: This works, thanks.  The error messages are pretty verbose, so I am going to have to manually make the `pip-requirements.txt` or `environment.yml` as suggested by @Nitred